# SKSprite.addChild at location

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In Swift, I have some code like this:

```
let wand = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Wand")
let item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Item")
...

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
   contact.bodyB.node!.removeAllActions()
   var imageToAdd = contact.bodyB.node?.name
   wand.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageToAdd!))
}
```

What I want is when a certain type of item touches the wand, I want to attach it to the wand.  The bitmap masks are set and all of that works perfectly.  But, when addChild adds the image, it's in the center of the wand and I want to control where it gets added.

Additional information.  I'm using physicsBody to animate the wand and the items.  The wand is controlled by the user touching the screen.  I tried a few ways to connect the two objects, SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA and SKPhysicsJointSliding.jointWithBodyA but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.  I think joining the two physics bodies is overkill for what I'm doing, but I could be wrong. My real goal is:

1) to add (or join) one sprite (the wand) to another sprite (an item)
2) allow the wand to continue to be controlled (animated) by the user touch
3) have control over the relative position of the item in relation to some point on the wand.

It's the third item that is tough.  Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your First Question:
The default position of the `SKSpriteNode` is (0,0) so if you add it to a parent node, the `SKSpriteNode` will thus be in the middle of the parent node's coordinate system. If you want to add the image a bit higher on the wand, lets say 100 points up, you just say `imageToAdd.position = CGPointMake(0,100)`. The child node will remain attached at that location. Another option of course is to create a joint, which isn't overkill at all if you want the wand and the attachment to have physics properties.

Your Second Question:
As long as you don't remove the physics body from the wand, it will still be there and could be controlled by the user.

Your Third Question:
The attached item will have a certain position relative to the wand since you created it as a child node. If you need to move the item you would create an `SKAction`. For example, if you needed to move the item down the wand, you could say:

```
moveDownWand = SKAction.moveByX(0.0, y: pointsToMoveDownBy, duration: someDuration)
attachedItem.runAction(moveDownWand)
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Neither of these had any effect:
wand.childNodeWithName(imageToAdd!)?.position = CGPointMake(-400, -400)

Or:
var moveDownWand = SKAction.moveByX(100, y: 100, duration: 0)
wand.childNodeWithName(imageToAdd!)?.runAction(moveDownWand)

Both ran, but the item was still added to the center of the wand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @M321K, you put me on the right track!  Here is what I did:

```
var nodeToAdd = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageToAdd!)
nodeToAdd.position = CGPointMake(0, -40)
wand.addChild(nodeToAdd)
```

I had to create the sprite and set it's position before adding it to the wand.  Huge help, thanks much.

Comment: yeah glad it worked! The order definitely matters haha!